# Do default template arguments enter into the one-definition rule?

Tags: c++, templates, one-definition-rule

Can multiple translation units have declarations of the same template with different default template arguments but the same definition?  For example, does the following code violate ODR if the translation units in `b.cpp` and `c.cpp` are linked together?

```
// a.hpp
template <bool> class x {...};

// b.cpp
template <bool = true> class x;
#include "a.hpp"
// uses of x<>

// c.cpp
template <bool = false> class x;
#include "a.hpp"
// uses of x<>
```

Comment: why do you need this? why not just use template<> x<true> and typedef it if needed?

Comment: In the real code, the default argument would be provided by a preprocessor macro that might be defined differently for different translation units, and I would like to make that as safe as possible to do (assuming `x<true>` and `x<false>` are not used in multiple definitions of the same class in multiple TUs, which is an obvious ODR violation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. The default argument does not *change* the definition of the template, it is the same. But it does change the definition of things that use the template when they provide no argument.

Consider:

```
// d.hpp
struct Broken {
   x<> member;
};
```

And uses of that header:

```
template <bool = true> class x;
#include "d.hpp"
// use Broken

template <bool = false> class x;
#include "d.hpp"
// Use Broken
```

Now your program is in violation of the ODR as one translation unit sees `Broken` as containing a `x<true>` while a different translation unit sees `Broken` as containing a `x<false>`.

A simpler safer approach would be to declare a constant in your .cpp's and don't modify the template:

```
// b.cpp
#include "a.hpp"  // no default argument
const bool default = true;
// any use of x<> becomes x<default> in the rest of the code
// similarly for c.cpp
```

The definition of the template is the same in all translation units and you get some effect similar to what you want. Note that `default` there has internal linkage so the different `default` objects would not cause a violation of the ODR.

The same kind of caution applies here as before, if you substitute the definition of `Broken` to use `default` and the value is defined to be different in different translation units, it will still be a violation of the ODR rule.

Comment: I would expect the definition of `Broken` to be a violation.  However, are you saying that having different variables (not shared between the TUs) with type `x<>` is safe?  In the real code, `x` will have other template parameters, so it will need to be in user-visible headers.

Comment: You should further explain your comment probably as part of the answer. It is not clear to me what you mean by *In real code...*. Technically, the default argument is part of the class declaration, and it **is** a violation of the ODR, although practically you will get away with it, as default arguments are injected when needed (i.e. in this case in the different translation units)

Comment: So just having the two declarations of `x` with different defaults *is* a violation, even if all external (cross-TU) interfaces using `x` explicitly specify the template argument?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock just use the common sense. Try to image things under-the-hood. If the same variable `x` is used (either directly or not) by some code not in accordance to how it's actually defined - this is a violation.